# locomotive.js listen to http and https

Tags: javascript, node.js, locomotivejs

i have a locomotive.js MVC project , and its listening on http.
i want to listen on https , and redirect all http to https.

i cant find the createServer of node.js, the only code i find is:
under /lib/node_modules/locomotive/lib/locomotive/cli/server.js

```
console.log('booting app at %s in %s environment', dir, env);

locomotive.boot(dir, env, function(err, server) {
  if (err) {
     throw err;
  }

  server.listen(port, address, function() {
     var addr = this.address();
     console.log('listening on %s:%d', addr.address, addr.port, addr);
  });
});
```

changed to :

```
console.log('booting app at %s in %s environment', dir, env);
var crypto = require('crypto'),
       fs = require("fs");
var privateKey = fs.readFileSync('/privatekey.pem').toString();
var certificate = fs.readFileSync('/certificate.pem').toString();
var https = require('https');
var credentials = crypto.createCredentials({key: privateKey, cert: certificate});
```

and i am kind of stuck now , any help ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not very well tested, but it seems to work:

```
  // start.js
  var locomotive  = require('locomotive');
  var app         = new locomotive.Locomotive();
  var http        = require('http');
  var https       = require('https');
  var fs          = require('fs');

  app.boot(__dirname, 'development', function(err, server) {
    var options = {
      key : fs.readFileSync('server.key'),
      cert: fs.readFileSync('server.crt')
    };
    https.createServer(options, server).listen(port, address);
  });
```

There's a couple of issues with it (hardcoded directory name and environment, and it doesn't include the HTTP-redirecting part), but those are minor.

Answer (score 0):

i will post my answer here , if someone see this question:

```
var fs = require("fs");

var options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('/privatekey.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('/certificate.pem')
};

var server = https.createServer(options, this);
return server.listen.apply(server, arguments);
```